# How to draw Chart using react-pdf library

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am going to draw some charts including doughnut, Pie, and Bar chart using the react-pdf library.
I was trying to draw it with Canvas but Seems like it's pretty complex and I don't have a better idea of it.
Please give me advice.
Thanks

Comment: I am referring to this document. 
https://react-pdf.org/repl

Comment: This [A simple pie chart in SVG](https://medium.com/hackernoon/a-simple-pie-chart-in-svg-dbdd653b6936) might get you going! Short and fairly comprehensible code.

Comment: Is it possible to use in react-pdf library elements?
https://react-pdf.org/repl

Comment: I think the important part here is how you are generating your charts, most chart libraries have various methods to export the data as images that may be useful.

Comment: I was trying to use canvas to draw chart but I'd love to know if it's possible to draw chart in <Document> element

Comment: An SVG can be treated as an image, so I'd say, copy the final code (near the end of the article) into yours and give it a try.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.
https://dev.to/finallynero/generating-pdf-documents-in-react-using-react-pdf-4ka7
Here are available components in react-pdf library. How can I use SVG? You can test here. https://react-pdf.org/repl